# Create multidimensional array from markup with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, flot

Basically I want to create a multidimensional array (array of arrays) with data from my markup with jQuery. I am using the array to display a [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) chart.
Heres a markup example:

```
    <ul id='test1'>
       <li data-key='02/06'>34</li>
       <li data-key='03/06'>15</li>
       <li data-key='04/06'>55</li>
    </ul>
```

Heres the format I would like it in:

```
  var array = [[02/06, 34], [03/06, 15], [04/06, 55]];
```

I've seen some `map()` and JSON examples, but couldnt really figure it from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create an array from html list?

```
// init empty array
var array = [];
// for each li in test1 ...
$('#test1 li').each(function() {
    // add to the array an new array with key und value
    array.push([ $(this).data('key'), $(this).text() ]);
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/seZQk/).

Comment: Mein freund do you have any expirence with Flot (the jQuery charts)?

Comment: I have very little expirence with flot.